# Meteor - Pass data to template

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm using Iron:Router and i have the following event in my template.

If the `Guests.update` function successful I want to redirect to the `thanks` template with the given properties.

**How can I receive the `success` property in my `thanks` template to use it there?**

```
Template.guest.events({
  'submit form': function(event, template){
    event.preventDefault();
    var foo = $('[name=foo]').val();
    Guests.update(this._id, {
      $set: {
        foo: foo,
      }
    }, function(error, result){
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        Router.go('thanks', { success:true, id: this._id } });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add parameters to your route definition:

```
Router.route('/thanks/:success/:_id', function () {
  let success = this.params.success;
  let _id = this.params._id;
  ...
});
```

Comment: You could do it with a Session variable as well. `Session.set('myObject',{ success:true, id: this._id })` and then `.get()` it from your template. Up to you.

Comment: The use of session variables is not recommended (global scope, no namespaces) unless absolutely required. Route parameters is a recommended pattern Using session variables will not allow state recovery if the URL is shared as a link.